# NodeJS fill "req" from other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got a NodeJS + Express Server setup with a router that looks like this:

```
app.route('/clients/:clientId)
    .get(users.ensureAuthenticated, clients.read)
    .put(users.ensureAuthenticated, clients.hasAuthorization, clients.update)
    .delete(users.ensureAuthenticated, clients.hasAuthorization, clients.delete);

app.param('clientId', clients.clientByID);
```

My Problem is that `users.ensureAuthenticated` fills the `req` parameter with the current user `req.user`.

Basically it does this: `req.user = payload.sub;` (with some other background stuff)

Then the `req.user` is available in the following functions e.g. `clients.update`, but not in `clients.clientByID`.

I know I could execute `users.ensureAuthenticated` in `clients.clientByID` again, but this would execute the code twice and be extra load on the server, right? I guess there must be another way, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation of express.

I'd like to know how I can access the `req.user` in `clients.clientByID` **without executing the code in `users.ensureAuthenticated` twice.**

Comment: It looks like you need a middleware for that , right ?

Comment: Let me know if my answer is sufficient or not.

Comment: Could you at least give feedback to the people who try to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you would like to execute `users.ensureAuthenticated` before `clients.clientByID` is executed. This can be achieved by using the `app.use` functionality. `app.use` handlers will get executed before the `app.param` and `app.route` handlers.

For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('First! Time to do some authentication!');
    next();
});

app.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
    console.log('Second! Now we can lookup the actual user.');
    next();
});

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Third! Here we do all our other stuff.');
    next();
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it works this way, really appreciate it. Very simple way. :)